# уменьшать количество слайдов vue-slick при уменьшении экрана браузера VUE.JS

Tags: vue.js

установил vue-slick как компонент. В опциях внутри скрипта сделал "карусели" slideToShow - 10. Но хотелось бы, чтобы при уменьшении экрана, количество отображаемых слайдов уменьшалось, а стили (размеры) не менялись. Помогите сообразить, что и как пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть такая штука у него как Responsive Display. Там для произвольной ширины можно указывать свое кол-во слайдов.

```js
$('.responsive').slick({
  dots: true,
  infinite: false,
  speed: 300,
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 4,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
        dots: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 480,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
      }
    }
    // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
    // settings: "unslick"
    // instead of a settings object
  ]
});
```

Comment: Сорри, минус был технический - из-за участника дух сообщества, которому я подтвердил тревогу на ответе. Добавил плюс для равновесия.